# Retrieving the increment value after seconds

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript. I want to increment the value after a certain time limit.

I have done the code like

```
<script>
 var c = 1;
window.setInterval(function() {
for(var i=0; i<30;i++) {
  console.log(c);
      clearInterval(c);
}



}, 200);
</script>
```

It outputs like 1 as 30 times immediately ..But i just want output like printing 1 and printing 2 after 3 second and printing 4 after 1 second like that 30 times.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: "I want to increment the value after a certain time limit" - Then use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code

```js
var c = 0;
var myTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
    c++;
    console.log(c);
    if(c == 30){
        window.clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
}, 2000);
```